# Display Term within Specified Custom Taxonomy in wordpress functions.php

Tags: wordpress

In functions.php in wordpress, I'm using a function to display information, if, that post is Tagged with a certain Term, but within a custom Taxonomy "not a regular (tag)"
The custom taxonomy will be "Special Info" or "special-info" as its slug

In my code below, its pretty straight forward, but how can i, "within the div" 
if the post has "special-info" taxonomy of "Block" Block being the Term of "Special Info" then Display "specified text here... " err i hope this makes sense

My Code
    function vision_contacts_description(){

```
if (has_term( 'colour-vision', 'brand' )) {

echo '<div class="repeat-descriptions" style=" padding-bottom: 10px;">Display Term within "Specified Custom Tax" Here.</div>' ;
}
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'vision_contacts_description', 25);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use *wp_get_post_term* function which will return all terms for your taxonomy (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms).

```
function someFuncName() {
    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_term($post->ID, 'special-info');
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if ('Block' === $term['name']) {
            //do something
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But i cant past that within the Div, i need it to echo out so i can incorporate it within some text..

Comment: I have found another path to this using Attributes for woocommerce, something i completely over looked.

So i no longer need this answered however would be nice to know if anyone would like to